# How to replace values in data frame with 2-level columns based on condition in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare

I use Python 3.6.1. Here is my data frame myDF I want to manipulate values for:

```
    a     b          c      
    a    X1    X2   X1    X2
 0  10    .     o    o     o
 1  20    .     o    o     o
 2  30    .     o    o     o
```

As you can see there are columns 'a', 'b', 'c' on level 0, and there are columns 'a', 'X1', 'X2' on level 1.

I need to compare whether a value in X1 is equal to a corresponding value in X2 under b/c and if so, remove the values. So the operation on the above data frame should return this:

```
    a     b          c      
    a    X1    X2   X1    X2
 0  10    .     o         
 1  20    .     o         
 2  30    .     o
```

This is how to get the source data frame:

```
import numpy
import pandas

X1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[10,'.','o'],[20,'.','o'],[30,'.','o']],
                      columns=['a','b','c'])
X2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[10,'o','o'],[20,'o','o'],[30,'o','o']],
                      columns=['a','b','c'])

myDF = pandas.concat([X1.set_index('a'), X2.set_index('a')],
                     axis='columns', keys=['X1','X2'])
myDF = myDF.swaplevel(axis='columns')[X1.columns[1:]]
myDF = myDF.reset_index(col_level=1, col_fill='a')
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
other = myDF.xs('X1', axis=1, level=-1)
main = numpy.where(myDF.eq(other, level=0), 'x', 'y')
pandas.DataFrame(main, index=myDF.index, columns=myDF.columns)
```

Which gives:

```
   a    b          c      
   a   X1    X2   X1    X2
0  F    T     F    T     T
1  F    T     F    T     T
2  F    T     F    T     T
```

And have no idea how to move forward ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My whole goal is to create a temporary dataframe with two columns, `['X1', 'X2']` so I can mask the rows where they are equal.  This gets me the two columns:

```
myDF.set_index(('a', 'a')).stack(0)

         X1 X2
(a, a)        
10     b  .  o
       c  o  o
20     b  .  o
       c  o  o
30     b  .  o
       c  o  o
```

I could save this to a temp name then manipulate in several additional lines.  Or I can perform the task in line with a `pipe`.

```
myDF.set_index(('a', 'a')).stack(0).pipe(
    lambda d: d.mask(d.X1 == d.X2, '')
)

         X1 X2
(a, a)        
10     b  .  o
       c      
20     b  .  o
       c      
30     b  .  o
       c
```

The rest is just accounting work to get things back into their place.

```
myDF.set_index(('a', 'a')).stack(0).pipe(
    lambda d: d.mask(d.X1 == d.X2, '')
).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).reset_index()

    a  b     c   
    a X1 X2 X1 X2
0  10  .  o      
1  20  .  o      
2  30  .  o
```

Comment: Nice solution :-) never saw pipe before :-)

Comment: Thank you so much :) Still need to understand better how it works. Nevertheless this is what I need. Just a remark: I use `set_index(('a'))`, so the data frame looks as expected:

Comment: I suspect that if you do, you'll have an `'a'` in the first level of the resulting columns but not the second.

Comment: Indeed, this is sth I want at the end.